# CSS Responsive media not responding

Tags: css

Alright so for some reason I've been trying to figure this out but can't. What's wrong with this? It's not being called at all. I'm trying to basically setup a simple responsive theme. 
It is kind of strange inside the notepad++, when I type like @medi it will be blue but once I add @media it will go black.

```
@media only screen and {min-width: 150px} and {max-width:600px} {

    body {
        width: 100%;
        font-size: 100%;
        background-color: black;
    }

    #header {
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your curly brackets to round brackets and it will start working..!

@media only screen and (min-width: 150px) and (max-width:600px)

Comment: You're always welcome :) Kindly mark this question as resolved if this fixed your issue :)